# memset is significantly faster then Eigen::Tensor SetZero()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, eigen, eigen3

I have changed Eigen::Tensor SetZero() call in my code to the memset call over the tensor data and observing significant better performance. Builded in VS 2016(SSE2 support should be enabled by default). Why does this happens? I have expected that Eigen::Tensor is highly optimized.

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#define MyLayoutType Eigen::RowMajor
#define Tf3 Eigen::Tensor<float, 3, MyLayoutType>
clock_t begin = clock();

Tf3 tensor(1000, 500, 20);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    tensor.setRandom();
    memset(tensor.data(), 0, tensor.size() * sizeof(float));
    // VS:
    //tensor.setZero();
}

clock_t end = clock();

double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
cout << "Total time elapsed: " << elapsed_secs << " 
secs" << endl;
cout << tensor(0, 0, 0);
```

On my env I got 2.1 for memset on avg and 2.3 for setZero. And setRandom operation is much more havy then memset. If I comment out tensor.setRandom() I get 0.4 for memset and 0.5 for setZero.IN real code difference in performance is bigger.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including your benchmark?

Comment: If you benchmark *just* a call to memset and never use the data later, the compiler might see that the zeroing has no visible effect, and skip it. Some code please!

Comment: @PasserBy sample code is attached..

Comment: I didn't test it, but this is the exact way __not__ to microbenchmark. The results are simply wrong. Look into google benchmarks if you are interested.